# Identity server single sign out, logout from server too

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

Here is my logout code that I use in relying party:

```
    FederationConfiguration cfg = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration;
    var fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
    fam.SignOut(false);
    var signOutRequestMessage = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(fam.Issuer), fam.Realm);
    return new RedirectResult(signOutRequestMessage.WriteQueryString());
```

And get logout from RP and redirected to Identity server "Signed out" page, but I still remain logged in at Identity server, is this expected behaviour? How can I change this so I get logged out from Identity server also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified HRDController:

```
 private ActionResult ShowSignOutPage(string returnUrl)
 {
   ....
   FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie(); //added this
   return View("Signout", realms);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends how the IdentityServer is doing authentication. If it's cookie based, then you *should* be logged out but if it's using something like integrated windows auth, then you're going to get automatically logged back in.

Comment: It is cookie based, but I messed with code alot. I set up wsfed and HRD on same view, and I am also authenticating users from HRD as wsfed based (since I register them with Simple membership). Anyway I got it working.